# How can I extract text from textboxes within a PDF in Python?

Tags: python, pdf

I'm not having any luck with `pyPDF2` or `PDFMiner`.  The tools always return `_______________` for the textboxes even if they are filled in.  Does anyone have any idea on how to extract the text within the textbox fields?

Comment: What did you try with pyPDF2/PDFMiner? what did it return?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583535/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129936/python-extract-text-from-pdfs, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract text fields, not a text. So you need something like this:

```
import sys
import six
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1

fp = open("c:\\tmp\\test.pdf", "rb")

parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
fields = resolve1(doc.catalog["AcroForm"])["Fields"]
for i in fields:
    field = resolve1(i)
    name, value = field.get("T"), field.get("V")
    print ("{0}:{1}".format(name,value))
```

Comment: it didnt work for me and made `KeyError: 'AcroForm'` error.